# What's the process name for IIS in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5

In Windows XP the process name for IIS was inetinfo.exe. I don't see it in Windows 7 in the task manager? It seems things have changed. Is it still a separate process?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Windows 7, w3wp.exe is the process that now responsible for serving the Web sites. Check this out [IIS 7 Architecture](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis-7-architecture/). By default, there is no Inetinfo.exe process or IIS Admin Service in Windows 7 in fact from Windows Vista onwards.

Comment: I had "show all processes to all users" unchecked. Now I see both inetinfo.exe and w3wp.exe. So inetinfo.exe is there.

Comment: If you have IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility installed only then you will see inetinfo.exe and IISADMIN service. Check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2008/05/07/where-is-iisadmin-service.aspx

Comment: This is also the exe to attach to for Visual Studio to debug and step through your server side code.  It also shows up with the Visual Studio remove debugger server.

Comment: why in the world wouldnt they call it `IIS.exe`?